# How can I select an object from a list based on specified preferences in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make an efficient function for selecting an object that best matches specified preferences where the order of the specified preferences matters, so the first preference is more important than the second. What I currently have is preference specifications, a class that constructs a specific object, and a class that constructs unique versions of that object. I want the best available version of the object and if it is not available, I want all versions of that object.

```
class myPreferences:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cheesePref = ['Blue Cheese', 'Cheddar'] #Importance value 5
        self.saucePref = ['Mayonaise' , 'Ketchup'] #Importance value 3
        self.breadPref = ['with Gluten', 'no Gluten'] #Importance value 2
        ## It is possible that an option arises with the same importance value as 
        ## another preference, so like vegetables with importance value 2

class Order: #Object consisting of all the sandwiches we found in the back 
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = ID
        self.sandwichesWeOwn = list[] #Populated with all the sandwiches
        self.uniquesandwiches = []
        for sandwich in in self.sandwichesWeOwn:
            US = uniqueSandwich(sandwich)
            self.uniquesandwiches.append(US)

class uniqueSandwich:
    def __init__ (self, sandwich):
        self.cheese = methodToDetermineCheese()
        self.sauce = methodToDetermineSauce()
        self.bread = methodToDetermineBread()
```

Below I have some scenarios with the results I want.

Scenario 1:
We have a list of 3 sandwiches:

1. Blue Cheese, Mayonaise, Gluten
2. Blue Cheese, Ketchup, Gluten
3. Cheddar, Ketchup, Gluten

Returns **Blue Cheese, Mayonaise, Gluten**

Scenario 2:
We have a list of 3 sandwiches.

1. Blue Cheese, Mayonaise
2. Blue Cheese, Gluten
3. Cheddar, Mayonaise, Gluten

Returns **Blue Cheese, Mayonaise**.

Scenario 3:
A list of 2 sandwiches.

1. Gouda, Ranch Dressing
2. Emertahler, Mustard, Brown Bread

Returns **Gouda, Ranch dressing** AND **Emertahler, Mustard, Brown Bread**

Is there an efficient way to make something like this happen in Python (without a bazillion if/for statements)

**EDIT:** The preferences are always in order, the first one being more important than the second one etc.

**EDIT 2:** The preferences have different weights, so I value the type of cheese more over the type of bread. So between Blue Cheese or Mayonaise+Gluten I would pick Blue Cheese. This is illustrated by the importance value

**EDIT 3:** It is possible in this case for a sandwich to not have an ingredient. So blue cheese + mayonaise is a valid sandwich.

Comment: Are the preferences always in the order of [MostPref, NextPref...]?

Comment: Yes they are, made an edit in original post

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
For each SandwichWeOwn as sandwich:
  compute a score based on ingredient's position in preference
  if it's the max possible score:
     return sandwich
  return SandwichWeOwn
```

For the "compute a score" part, the simplest would be to use a "lower is better approach" so a score of zero is a perfect match, anything else is not. A Q&D version:

```
def score_ingredient(ingredient, prefs):
   # here we expect prefs to be a list ie ['Blue Cheese', 'Cheddar']
   try:
       return prefs.index(item)
   except ValueError:
       return sys.maxint

def score_sandwich(sandwich, prefs):
    # here we excepts "pref" to be a dict of lists, ie
    # {"cheese": [...], "bread": [...], etc}
    score = 0
    for ingredienttype, ingredient_prefs in prefs:
        ingredient = getattr(sandwich, ingredienttype)
        score += score_ingredient(ingredient, ingredient_prefs)
    return score
```

EDIT : as you mention, this won't pass the test for scenario 2, but then you'll have to explain 1/ why sandwich 1 should win in this case and 2/ how a sandwich is a sandwich without bread xD

Comment: I have considered this, but when looking at scenario 2 this doesn't work for me. The score for sandwich 3 would be greater than sandwich 1, but I want sandwich 1 to be the returned value. I also considered adding wieghts to each criteria (like type of cheese scores would be multiplied by x) but even in such a scenario cases could arise where the incorrect sandwich is returned.

Comment: Your scenario 2's first sandwich is incorrect - a sandwich HAS bread, else it's not a sandwich <g>. Same for your scenario 3's first sandwich BTW. But even if we consider that a sandwich could have no bread, you will have to explain _why_ scenario 2 should select the first sandwich instead of the third or the second or the whole list.

Comment: I've made an edit for clarifications. The different selection criteria have different weights, but can also have the same weight. Sorry for the confusion. In this case, it is possible for only Mayonaise to be considered a sandwich for instance.

Comment: @Don I suggest you revise your preference model to have a "Preference" object per "ingredient type" (=> "cheese", "sauce", etc) with a "weight" attributes, a "score" function and possibly a "if_missing" callback func (strategy pattern) called by "score" if the ingredient is missing in the sandwich (ie the "MyPreferences" object would then have three "Preference" instances as attributes).  Then you can pass to your `bread_preference` instance a `if_missing` callback that returns max score.